# OpenMP для распараллеливания множественного запуска эксперимента

Tags: c++, openmp

Мне нужно n раз запустить цикл, при этом один проход цикла равен одному эксперименту, т.е. просто какой -то подсчет информации.

```
for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k){
    xo = 0 + rand()%w;
    yo = 0 + rand()%h;
    cout << calc() << endl; // выводим результат подсчета 
}
```

Функция calc считает у меня среднее значение яркости пикселя по изображению с координатами xo,yo и заданными w, h.

При этом данные у меня загружаются вне цикла и записываются в мой экземпляр класса Image.
При попытке написать директиву

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel for
```

у меня всё валится
что-то посчитает, где - то верные значения выведет, где-то мусор какой-то, а потом сообщение об ошибке.

Может ли ошибка быть в том, что я в каждом потоке работаю с одним и тем же экземпляром класса? Т.е. для первого потока - я задаю посчитать среднее по изображению с координатами (x1,y1), в итоге у меня поле arr класса Image уже содержит данные именно для этих координат, и тут же задаю посчитать среднее для других координат. Если ошибка в этом, то как можно распараллеливание процесс?

Comment: Да, логическая ошибка в том, что Вы пытаетесь работать с одним объектом в разных потоках. Но валится программа не совсем по этой причине. Во-первых, если я правильно понял суть задачи, то нужно сначала сделать массив объектов, которые будут обрабатываться этими потоками. Во-вторых, уберите cout из цикла - операции ввода/вывода очень медленные и они будут мешать работе (и вообще, cout нельзя здесь использовать без синхронизации). Выведите все результаты после параллельной секции. В-третьих, Вы в прагме должны еще правильно задать роли переменных: кто общий для всех, кого склонировать и т.п.

Comment: Кроме того, rand() не самый лучший вариант для выполнения в разных потоках одновременно - он не является потокозащищенным, насколько я понимаю. Если Вы используете С++11, то может лучше использовать его генераторы (из STL) - отдельный генератор на каждый поток (но это в теории. я сам не опробовал еще их поведение с OpenMP).

Comment: @Vladimir Т.е., как я поняла, мне нужно создать массив из экземпляров класса?

Comment: по этому участку кода очень сложно понять, что на самом деле нужно. `xo,yo, calc()` - это члены класса и этот цикл внутри класса? Если да, то скорее всего, придется делать массив объектов, а цикл делать вне методов класса. Если же это просто отдельные переменные и функция `calc()` - обычная функция, то у Вас большие проблемы: по вызову `calc()` я предположу, что xo и yo - глобальные переменные - и это проблема для OpenMP (т.к. получается, что в одну ячейку пытаются писать все потоки).